# what are "ReverseTransform" and "MergeTreeReverse" mean in the clickhouse explain pipeline?

Tags: clickhouse

what are "ReverseTransform" and  "MergeTreeReverse" mean in the clickhouse explain pipeline?

table

```sql
CREATE TABLE device_info
(
`event_time` DateTime,
`create_time` DateTime DEFAULT now(),
`product_id` String,
`platform` String,
`app_version` String,
`sdk_version` String,
`os_version` Strin,
`model` String,
`device_id` String,
`device_type` String,
`device_cost` Int64,
`data_id` String
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(event_time)
ORDER BY (event_time, product_id, platform, app_version, sdk_version, os_version, model)
TTL event_time + toIntervalDay(7)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

```sql
SELECT
   event_time AS eventTime,
   launch_cost AS launchCost,
   device_id,
   data_id
FROM device_info
WHERE (device_id = 'xxxxxxx') AND (product_id = 'xxxxxxx') AND (device_type IN ('type1')) AND (event_time >= 'xxxx') AND (event_time <= 'xxxxx')
ORDER BY event_time DESC
```

explain pipeline

what are "ReverseTransform" and  "MergeTreeReverse" mean in the explain pipeline?

[explain pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svgGG.png)

in the trace log I find a statement is
"MergingSortedTransform: Merge sorted 645 blocks,861 rows in 5.927999977 sec. what is the  statement mean?

appreciate for your answer! thx